# Postgres 9.1 Type of SETOF record

Tags: postgresql, types, record

I have dynamicly generated SELECT. I try to return result as SETOF RECORD. Sth like that:

```
CREATE FUNCTION test(column_name text) RETURNS SETOF RECORD AS $$
DECLARE
   row  RECORD;
BEGIN
   FOR row IN EXECUTE 'SELECT ' || quote_ident(column_name) || ' FROM dates'
LOOP
   RETURN NEXT row;
END LOOP;
RETURN;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

When I try:

```
SELECT * FROM test('column1');
```

I get this:

```
ERROR:  a column definition list is required for functions returning "record"
```

I know that column1 is integer type:

```
SELECT * FROM test('column1') f(a int);
```

result is correct, because I know that this is going to be Integer type.

When I try:

```
SELECT * FROM test('column1') f(a varchar);
```

I get error:

```
ERROR:  wrong record type supplied in RETURN NEXT
DETAIL:  Returned type integer does not match expected type character varying in column 1.
```

Now my question:
What to do to get rid of part of querty where I define types 'f(a int)'. It should by feasible because Postgres knowns what is returned type. I tried with IMMUTABLE options, but unsuccessfully.

Comment: How can `column1` be an `int` in the first example and be a `varchar` in the second example?

Comment: It is not, but I wanted to show that postgres knows what is return type.

Comment: It seems to me what you are doing is exactly the same as `select column1 from dates`. Why do you need a function to return one only column from a table? What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could cast the value to text inside the function, and declare that the function `RETURNS SETOF text`.  You can also return the whole result set at once; no need to iterate explicitly.

```
CREATE TABLE dates (column1 int, column2 date);
INSERT INTO dates VALUES (1, date '2012-12-22'), (2, date '2013-01-01');

CREATE FUNCTION test(column_name text) RETURNS SETOF text AS $$
BEGIN
   RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'SELECT '
      || quote_ident(column_name) || '::text FROM dates';
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

Now `SELECT test('column1');` yields:

```
 test 
------
 1
 2
(2 rows)
```

... and (with my locale settings) `SELECT test('column2');` yields:

```
    test    
------------
 2012-12-22
 2013-01-01
(2 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify OUT parameters corresponding to the columns you want to return.

Comment: That's not necessary with `RETURN SETOF RECORD`

Comment: But what when I don't know how many parameters I'm going to return?